# Bottom Bracket Drive side cup Problem

Tags: bottom-bracket

Hello i cannot get my bottom bracket cup on the right side out (drive side) just checking that it is clockwise to get it out, the non drive side cup i got out really easily, i’ve tried wd40 and it is moving inside but not screwing out.

Thank you :) .

• 16” 2020 carrera hellcat
• Square taped bottom bracket

Answer (score 1):

A threaded bottom bracket cup on the right, drive side of the bike does indeed unthread/loosen by rotating the cup clockwise. If this is a cartridge bearing bottom bracket, the body, bearing and spindle assembly--essentially the bulk of the bottom bracket--will come out the right side together with the cup.  A loose ball bearing bottom bracket features the cups with their ball bearings separate from each other and the square taper spindle.

In any case you'll want to use the correct bottom bracket tool (almost always a splined tool whose number and shape of the splines mate perfectly into the receiving aspect of the cup.  Especially on the drive side, it can take a great deal of force to break loose the cup's threads. While grease or anti-seize paste is best for thread treatment prior to installing a BB, some folks utilize a thread locker (aka Loctite) instead.  Even a medium strength version of this stuff combined with achieving the appropriate torque of around 40 N-m make removing such a treated cup impossible without damaging something.

It's unclear whether you have got the drive side cup moving. If the cup is spinning in place without moving out, that is a bad sign. Could infer thread damage of the shell. Tapping the left side of the spindle or putting some lateral pressure there directed to the right while you rotate (clockwise) the right cup may give enough thread purchase to start the cup moving out.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate this and the bb does spin freely it’s just not as smooth as before hence why i’m replacing it. The bb on the drive side seemed to be sized as i’m not getting enough purchase to undo it so i’m going go on for a bigger spanner and anti slip tool for the bb to see where i go from there.